# Discharge on fluorescent light

Tags: electricity, fluorescence

when the voltage is very low, fluorescent lights will not light fully as the voltage is not enough to generate a discharge. But I could see a glow at both the ends. When I touch on the outside of the fluorescent tube, I can actually increase the length of the glow. If the voltage is good enough, using both hands, I can increase the length of the glow from both sides and get the complete discharge.

My questions, what is happening in this scenario?

Thanks,
GL

Comment: It looks somebody already answered a similar question here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/41503/why-sometimes-touching-old-flickering-tube-lights-starts-them-properly?rq=1